# How I can declare 3d array with different sizes

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm trying to achieve something like this:
[image]

What does it means? In shortly, firstly I have some data (grandfather for example) that each of them have **different number** of sons, and each sons have 1 son.

I thought about using 3D array, but the different number of the second array will not working on this method. How I can achieve it then?

Comment: If each grandfather has a variable number of sons, why not use a dynamic data structure like a `List<Son> sons`? If you still want static arrays you have to always allocate the maximum number of sons and have some `null` pointers in there.

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt Then I'll should have a list of each 'grandfather'?

Comment: This looks a lot like a `Tree`, have you considered using one of the many .Net tree implementations? I don't know anything about [this implementation](https://www.nuget.org/packages/TreeCollections/), but there are many others out there if you google around a little.

Comment: Why not make a Class `FamillyMember` and have this class have a field 'List<FamillyMember> sons' and a field 'string name'. you have one instance `FamillyMember[] Grandfathers` with your 3 original grandfathers and they contain an endless deep variable structure of children.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this, for example:

```
List< List < Element > >
```

Comment: But I will need a list of each 'grandfather' no? Im trying to do it all in one.

Answer (score 0):

```
        var multiDimesionalList = new List<List<string>>
        {
            new List<string> { "List one, Child One", "List one, Child Two", "List one, Child Three" },
            new List<string> { "List two, Child One", "List two, Child Two", "List two, Child Three" }
        };
```

You can just create a list of lists as many levels deep as you need to create the hierarchy you desire.

Answer (score 0):

here is one approach:

test class that will be used in example:

```
public class MyClassOfSomeData
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    //etc...
    public List<MyClassOfSomeData> Children = new List<MyClassOfSomeData>();
}
```

.. and it's usage in lists of endless levels

```
//define list of top level classes, left part of your image, or grandfathers as you call it
List<MyClassOfSomeData> listOfTopLevelData = new List<MyClassOfSomeData>();
listOfTopLevelData.Add(new MyClassOfSomeData() { ID = 1, Name = "top level one " });
listOfTopLevelData.Add(new MyClassOfSomeData() { ID = 2, Name = "top level two" });
//you can also add new like this
MyClassOfSomeData thirdGrandFather = new MyClassOfSomeData();
thirdGrandFather.ID = 3;
thirdGrandFather.Name = "top level 3";
//now, define "father", second from left on your picture
MyClassOfSomeData secondLevel = new MyClassOfSomeData();
secondLevel.ID = 31;
secondLevel.Name = "second Leve";
//define third level
MyClassOfSomeData thirdLevel = new MyClassOfSomeData();
thirdLevel.ID = 311;
thirdLevel.Name = "third Level";
//add it to children collection of secondLevel class
secondLevel.Children.Add(thirdLevel);
//...and add that secondLevel class to first level children, as a child of grandfather
thirdGrandFather.Children.Add(secondLevel);
//add third grandfather to top level collection
listOfTopLevelData.Add(thirdLevel);
//so, now you have this
// top level 1
// top level 2
// top level 3
//  L___ second Level
//    L___ third level
```

Comment: Very nice solution... but If I wants to get all the second level of the top level? I meant all the sons of the first grandfather, and not all of them. is it possible?

Comment: @web i'm not sure i understand. Use ID's of my example to show where you want to add children. I showed you basic example, you can add as many children on any class. And on children's children ...

Comment: @WebO yes that is possible. Each instance `MyClassOfSomeData` or `FamillyMember` if you go with the layout of my comment contains a List with his children. Find the instance of the Grandfather whose kids you want to obtain and just print out his List.